# php: convert array variable to string?

Tags: php, string

string converting to array

```
<?php
$value1 = "Hello, world";
$convert = explode(" ",$value1);

echo $convert[1]; //Hello
echo $convert[2]; //world

// i convert particular number of array  to string
$s = implode(" ", $convert[2]);
?>
```

I want output : `world` but I get this error message:

> Error:
>   Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in

I tried, but not done any one help

Comment: array starts from `0` index :) so try `$s = implode(" ",$convert[1]);`

Comment: Do you only want the output world from the string value1?

Comment: CS GO is right. Implode is imploding an array, not a string.

Comment: @lolka_bolka CS GO did not say that, but you ARE right... `implode()` expects second parameter to be array, string given. Change that and everything will work "as expected" (whatever you are expecting)

Comment: @AresDraguna I sad CS GO has right, AND implode... :)

Comment: IS you question solved or do you need more information?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the output `world`, then this should work:

```
<?php

    $value1 = "Hello, world";
    $convert = explode(", ",$value1);

    //echo $convert[0]; //Hello
    echo $convert[1]; //world


?>
```